# Multiply a (n x 1) matrix by (n x m) matrix coefficient wise

Tags: matrix, eigen

I am trying to implement the following Bézier curve degree elevation equation using **Eigen** library:

[image]

The following code snippet is working to calculate the new control points. In this code `degree` is the variable `n` from the equation.

```
const size_t dimension = 3; // 2d or 3d points
const size_t degree = 3;
const size_t order = degree + 1;

// Create and fill Eigen::Matrix with original control points
Eigen::Matrix<double, order, dimension> P;

    // Fill matrix with original control points. Should be degree + 1 points.

// Calculate the new control points
Eigen::Matrix<double, degree, 1> M1 = FillElevationMatrix<double, degree>();
Eigen::Matrix<double, degree, 1> M2;
M2.setOnes();
M2 -= M1;
Eigen::Matrix<double, degree, dimension> Q;
for (size_t i = 0; i < degree; ++i) {
    Q.block(i, 0, 1, dimension) = (M1.row(i) * P.row(i)) + (M2.row(i) * P.row(i + 1));
}
```

Is there is a way to eliminate the loop and do the calculation in one shot? Or, more generically, **How do I multiply a column of scalars (n x 1 matrix) by a n x m matrix so that just the corresponding row of the first matrix is multiplied by each element of the corresponding row in the second matrix in one operation?**. The loop is doing it one row at a time. What I would like is something like this:

`Q = (M1 * P.block(0, 0, degree, dimension)) + (M2 * P.block(1, 0, degree, dimension));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop corresponds to multiplying with diagonal martrices, i.e:

```
Q = M1.asDiagonal() * P.topRows<degree>() + M2.asDiagonal() * P.bottomRows<degree>();
```

For initializing `M1` and `M2`, also have a look at [LinSpaced](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ad8098aa5971139a5585e623dddbea860) and [reverse](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a38ea394036d8b096abf322469c80198f).

Comment: Just what I was hoping for and more! I am new to Eigen so I appreciate the added tips.